# .net framework execution was aborted by escalation policy because of out of memory

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net, sql-server-2012, binaryfiles

I am using  Net framework 4.0 and Sql Server 2012 for the development. There is an error occurring randomly while performing database operation in the web application in asp.net. I have call some sql queries from code behind file. It is occurring for large document with size greater than 300KB. How to increase size.

EDIT :

It is mainly occurring while view image files and saving binary data in the database

Below is the code where I got error

```
        int isUpdateIDProof = 1;
        SqlParameter paramInsertIDProof = null;
        SqlCommand cmdInsertIDProof = new SqlCommand("OnBoarding_InsertUploadedIDProof", con);
        cmdInsertIDProof.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        paramInsertIDProof = new SqlParameter("@FileCaption", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        paramInsertIDProof.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        paramInsertIDProof.Value = txtIDProofDescription.Text;
        cmdInsertIDProof.Parameters.Add(paramInsertIDProof);

        paramInsertIDProof = new SqlParameter("@FileData", SqlDbType.VarBinary,1000000000);
        paramInsertIDProof.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        paramInsertIDProof.Value = OnBoardingFileData;
        cmdInsertIDProof.Parameters.Add(paramInsertIDProof);

        paramInsertIDProof = new SqlParameter("@FileNames", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        paramInsertIDProof.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        paramInsertIDProof.Value = fileName;
        cmdInsertIDProof.Parameters.Add(paramInsertIDProof);

        //execute SQL COMMAND 
        con.Open();
        cmdInsertIDProof.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: Can you please post some code?  

The most likely cause of this is either:  
1) Your image files\binary data are actually too large  
2) You are not correctly disposing your SqlDataReaders\SqlConnections  
3) You are sharing SqlDataReaders\SqlConnections between multiple threads

Comment: Yes this problem occurs for the large size document

Comment: Seems to be issue in your stored procedure. Could you post this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not any issue with your `code`. Its all about the memory leakage at your database server by the way you are storing the image. If you are using any sql server project dll for compressing and decompressing the binary data, please check this.

To hide your error, you can restart sql server service. It will automatically refresh the memory and will start working fine. I had the same problem some year back.

Comment: Thanks Cody. I just restarted the service and what surprise. My images are uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This is not from asp.net coding side issue. This happens in Sql server when processing your request and finding less memory to execute the script.

I was also facing this issue in one of the criteria where we are running SQL CLR stored procedures and facing the similar issue.

Below article may helps:- 
https://www.johnsansom.com/sql-server-memory-configuration-determining-memtoleave-settings/

This article explains on "memToleave"  which is virtual address space for efficient memory usage.